# Установить selected на прежнее место после отправки данных из форм

Tags: php, html

Делаю форму регистрации, и если по нажатии "зарегистриоваться" была ошибка, то нужно, чтобы введенные данные не сбрасывались. С формами нет проблем, но с select возникли. Я придумал сделать так...

```
<select name="bday">
                        <option value="0">День</option>
                        <option <?php if($data['bday'] == 01)echo selected?>>01</option>
                        <option <?php if($data['bday'] == 02)echo selected?>>02</option>
                        <option <?php if($data['bday'] == 03)echo selected?>>03</option>
                        <option <?php if($data['bday'] == 04)echo selected?>>04</option>
                        <option <?php if($data['bday'] == 05)echo selected?>>05</option>
                        <option <?php if($data['bday'] == 06)echo selected?>>06</option>
                        <option <?php if($data['bday'] == 07)echo selected?>>07</option>
                        <option <?php if($data['bday'] == 08)echo selected?>>08</option>
                        <option <?php if($data['bday'] == 09)echo selected?>>09</option>
                        <option <?php if($data['bday'] == 10)echo selected?>>10</option>
                        ...
                        ...
                        ...
```

но мне кажется это неправильно. Столько проверок... с учетом дней, месяцев и лет это более 100 штук. Бред же? )

Подскажите, как лучше сделать.

P.S. тем более возникает какая-то магическая ошибка с числами в условии `08` и `09`:
`Parse error: Invalid numeric literal`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для перебора всех вариантов воспользуйтесь циклом. А про магию с числами 08 и 09 почитайте здесь: [восьмеричное число](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.integer.php).

Пример цикла:

```
<select name="bday">
    <?php $bday = intval($data['bday']); ?>
    <option value="0" <?php if($bday == 0) echo selected ?>>День</option>
    <?php for($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++): ?>
        <option <?php if($bday == $i) echo selected ?>><?php printf("%02d", $i); ?></option>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Ой, спасибо, с числами разобрался. А как здесь цикл применить? Он должен вывести те же условия, просто чтобы руками всё не прописывать?